# Mysql syntax update set value string replace with value another column

Tags: mysql, sql-update

Please help me! many thank

```
UPDATE `articles` SET `content` = REPLACE(`content`, 'alt=""', 'alt="`articles_title`"'')
```

`articles_title`: value column

Comment: what you actually want to do - what is the meaning of 'alt=""', 'alt="articles_title"''

Answer (score 1):

Column names aren't replaced inside strings. You need to use the `CONCAT()` function to concatenate strings.

```
UPDATE `articles` 
SET `content` = REPLACE(`content`, 'alt=""', CONCAT('alt=", `articles_title`, '"'))
```

Comment: Hi @Barmar. You are wonderful. Many and many and many thank you! 1000 Like for you